# Testing if a dataframe is shuffled

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing

I want to test if my dataframe is shuffled (not equal). I see that unittest has a assertEqual and a asserNotEqual possibility. I want to do the assertNotEqual, but then for assert_frame_equal (so assert_frame_not_equal). How can I rewrite this function such that it tests for inequality?

```
class TestOp(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_random_shuffle(self):
        result = oper.randomly_shuffle_locations_test(stock_file)
        assert_frame_equal(result, stock_file)
```

Comment: IMHO you should instead test that `sorted(result) == stock_file`. This ensures that no elements are added or lost (which testing inequality would not), also it could randomly shuffle to the original order.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I already tested that in a way with a different function. Your second point is valid only the chances of that being true are astronomically small so no worries there.

Comment: If there is no `assert_frame_not_equal`, could you just use a regular "assert true" with a condition testing for inequality?

Comment: yes, that would be an option :-)